# Google translate api auth issue

Tags: python, api, google-api, google-translate

I followed all Google translate API steps and configured SDK as well as per given on https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/#deb

Also I set auth key using

```
gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file=[PATH]
```

Now my curl request works and gives response as expected

```
curl -s -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    -H "Authorization: Bearer "$(gcloud auth print-access-token) \
    --data "{
  'q': 'The Great Pyramid of Giza (also known as the Pyramid of Khufu or the
        Pyramid of Cheops) is the oldest and largest of the three pyramids in
        the Giza pyramid complex.',
  'source': 'en',
  'target': 'es',
  'format': 'text'
}" "https://translation.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2"
```

But when I write python program as given in - https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/translate/cloud-client/quickstart.py

It generated Auth issue

```
>>> translate_client = translate.Client()
>>> text = u'Hello, world!'
>>> target = 'ru'
>>> translation = translate_client.translate(text,target_language=target)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google/cloud/translate_v2/client.py", line 234, in translate
    method='POST', path='', query_params=query_params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google/cloud/_http.py", line 293, in api_request
    raise exceptions.from_http_response(response)
google.api_core.exceptions.Forbidden: 403 POST https://translation.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?target=ru&q=Hello%2C+world%21: Request had insufficient authentication scopes.
```

What can be the issue here? Any help much appreciated

Comment: Does it work if you explicitly point to the key file of the service account with `export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/path/to/credentials.json"` prior to running the Python script?

Comment: I have the same problem. have you solved it?